# Solvers for Differential Equations are not converging (Julia)

Tags: julia, ode, differential-equations, noise

**Problem description**

I am trying to get numerical solutions for the stochastic schrödinger equation. A simplified version of the equation that I am solving for the ostensible state vector `x`:

`dx/dt = -i*A*alpha(t)*x`

where A is an arbitrary matrix and `alpha(t)` is a complex Gaussian noise processes with zero mean and given covariance and arbitrary pseudocovariance (given the total kernel is positive semidefinite). For example the covariance of `alpha(t)` looks like:

`E[alpha(t) alpha(t')] = e^{-i\omega(t-t')}`

**Methodology**

To construct the noise process I generated the whole (timesteps x timesteps)-dim covariance matrix and did an eigenvector eigenvalue decomposition to get the matrix `B` so that `B*B^{\dagger} = e^{-i\omega t}`. Then I constructed the process `alpha(t) = B * X` with X a Gaussian variable with covariance as the identity matrix and mean 0. Then `alpha(t)`should have the desired properties. (Is there a better method to generate the desired colored noise? I also tried with `alpha(t) = beta_1(t) + i*beta_2(t)` and `beta` real valued processes, and the covariance  `E[(beta_1(t) + i*beta_2(t))(beta_1(t) - i*beta_2(t))] = cos(\omega(t-t')) - i*sin(\omega(t-t'))`, with the same problems that I will explain now.)

The physical property, the density operator, can be computed as average over the outer product of different trajectories of the ostensible state vector `x`. The trace of the density operator should stay constant at 1 (with some fluctuations due to the noise). I used different solvers for (R)ODE but for all of them the trace is diverging, for some of them very rapidly to ~10^20, for some to ~100, but for none of them it is staying constant as it should. I used 100,000 trajectories which should be enough.

For the (R)ODE I first generated a trajectory for the noise, then passed it to the correct shape and then passed it to the RODESolver:

```
my_noise = NoiseGrid(t, noise_trajectory)

# Solve the RODE
prob_RODE = RODEProblem(f, u0, tspan, p, noise = my_noise)
sol_RODE = solve(prob_RODE, RandomEM(), dt=dt)
```

For ODE I also computed the trajectory first but then took `alpha(t)` as time-varying parameter.

```
noise_trajectory = fun_noise_trajectory()  # computes a trajectory for the noise
    
function f(du, u, p, t)
    parameter_index = Int(floor(t / dt)) + 1  # Adjust index calculation
    my_noise = noise_trajectory[parameter_index]  # Get parameter value at the index
    du .= - 1im * A * u .* my_noise
end;

p = (noise_trajectory, )

# Solve the ODE
prob_ODE = ODEProblem(f, u0, tspan, p)
sol_ODE = solve(prob_ODE, RK4(), dt=dt)
```

**Questions**

I think the problem comes from the different solvers, since the solutions differ a lot for them. RODE works better than ODE when comparing with the analytical solutions.

What does `RODE` do differently than `ODE`, if one also passes a already computed trajectory to the solver?

What is the `RandomEM()` solver doing numerically (it is the only implemented solver for `RODE`?

Which method should I use to get an accurate result?

Comment: Numerical ODE solvers are for smooth ODE. If the right side has noise terms or is entirely noise, then that is the exact opposite. Formulate the problem as SDE system and apply dedicated SDE solvers.

Comment: @LutzLehmann For ODE I can take time varying parameters. So if I compute the noise trajectory for each timestep first, can't I then just pass the respective value of the noise as parameter value to the ODE?

Comment: Yes, but then the DE is arbitrarily stiff and you get the mentioned convergence problems. Btw., what exactly is the nature of the convergence problems? Is it related to refining the error tolerance or to refining the resolution of the noise term approximation?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Oh okay, thanks! I don't know what the nature of the convergence problems is, they still appear when I decrese timestep and increase tolerance.  I tried to solve a modified problem as an SDE with a real OU-process and covariance e^{-theta|t-t'|} but the solutions still diverge. But for SDE solver I don't know how to construct the complex noise, I chose the RODE method since arbitrary noise trajectories can be passed. Do you know how to change an RODE to an SDE for complex noise?